# How to solve errors in Kaggle while setting up PyTorch environment

Tags: python, pytorch, kaggle, wandb

I'm new to Kaggle Notebooks. I'm trying to set up adamp, torchsummary, pytorch_model_summary.
But it keeps raising an error. How should I sort out my problem?

Python version is 3.7.12

```
import numpy as np
import random
import os
import pandas as pd
import cv2
import torch
import torchvision
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et
import shutil

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import argparse

!pip install pytorch_model_summary
!pip install adamp
!pip install torchsummary

from adamp import AdamP
import pytorch_model_summary
import torchsummary

import albumentations as A
from albumentations.pytorch.transforms import ToTensorV2
```

This is Error message.

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fe9da8b3e50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/pytorch-model-summary/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pytorch_model_summary (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pytorch_model_summary
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa1c93ee190>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/adamp/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement adamp (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for adamp
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f1ffc9f3b50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/torchsummary/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torchsummary (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torchsummary
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_17/1756901018.py in <module>
     17 get_ipython().system('pip install torchsummary')
     18 
---> 19 from adamp import AdamP
     20 import pytorch_model_summary
     21 import torchsummary

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'adamp'
```